# How I get percentage value instead of pixel value?

Tags: javascript, width, percentage

```
if ($C.getElement(".side-bar")) {
        $C.setEvent("click",".side-bar",function() {
            var element=document.getElementById('navbar');
            style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
            alert(style.width);
            /*if(style.width !== '60px'){
                if ( this.childElementCount == 2){
                    var nodes = this.childNodes;
                    for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
                        if( nodes[i].className == 'nav nav-second-level'){
                            if(nodes[i].style['display'] === 'block'){ 
                                    nodes[i].style.display = '';
                                }
                            else{
                                    nodes[i].style.display= 'block';
                                }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }*/
        });
     }
```

In this code I need to be to check the width of navbar ,If width of navbar is not equal-to 6% of total screen then I need to execute the operation (here given an example for width of navbar equal-to 60px).This is happened  when I put converted the width in to percentage instead of pixel.Can anyone help me to get the percentage value instead of pixel value?

I'm added the structure of navbar on below

```js
document.getElementById("bttn").addEventListener("click" , function (){
document.getElementById("navbar").classList.add("navbar-after-click");
});
```

```css
body,html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
#navbar{ 
 height:300px;
  background-color:blue;
  }
.navbar{
 width:15%;
}
.navbar-after-click{
  width:6%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">

</div>
<button id="bttn">click me to change the width to 6%</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no direct method to convert the value to percentage value.

Though not tested but you can try this way

```
var yourElement = document.getElementById('someId');
var elemWidth = window.getComputerStyle(yourElement).getPropertyValue("width");
var parent = yourElement.parentNode;
var parentWidth =window.getComputerStyle(parent).getPropertyValue("width");
var calculatePercentage = (100*parseFloat(elemWidth)/parentWidth)+'%';
```